# Add/Remove features on Server 2012 R2 fails when joined to domain (Offline)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I am trying to add/remove features from one server using the GUI Server Manager tool on Server 2012 R2. I have 2 servers doing this and both air connected to the same network and have no access to the internet.

Upon trying to add/remove a feature from either of SERVER 1 or SERVER 2 I get the following error.

```
Failed to open the runspace pool. The Server Manager WinRM plug-in might be corrupted or missing.
```

I did a winrm/config restore. On WinRM/config the output was Restore_OUTPUT. On the winrm/plugin it shows the following error `0x8033803B`. It also states the plugin folder is missing or in an invalid format. Google does not show a lot of information for this error.

I am wondering what the WinRM plugin corruption looks like if the server can connect with Server Manager on the other servers. So am wondering if this is an issue that the servers are not connected to the Internet. Does the Server Manager Add/REmove only work while connected to the internet because previous Servers OSs did not.

**EDIT1:** Checked the GPO for "Remote Shell Access" it is set to "Not Configured" so this is not causing the issue.

Also this still does not fix the WinRM runspace pool issue.

**EDIT2:** Added information on the PSSession

```
Name:    Microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows
PSVersion: 3.0
Startup Script: 
RunAsUser: 
Permission: NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed BUILTIN\Administrators Access Allowed
```

**EDIT3:** Added required information
[image: OUTPUT]

**EDIT 4:** I rebuilt the server and was able to add/remove features before I joined it to the domain. When I joined it to the domain I get the Runspace Pool error. So this has to be a GPO thing. Suggestions on GPO settings to check? Remote Shell Access is set to NOT CONFIGURED so it should be allowing connections.

Comment: Can you do it locally or remotely with PowerShell? `install-windowsfeature`  There is no internet requirement for Server Manager.  Intranet is completely fine.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I have installed a few functions through PowerShell but I am unsure if all required roles have been installed or installed correctly.

Comment: Install-WindowsFeature uses most of the same underlying mechanisms as the ServerManager UI.  Were you able to use it remotely with the `-ComputerName` parameter against the computer the UI could not configure?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I was able to install to install the feature I need which was WSUS but now I get this error when I run the postinstall.

Comment: You "...cleaned registry and files..." I have no idea what you did there or have done before, and you've likely taken your system beyond what I can cleanly answer as a constrained Stack Exchange type question. Best of luck, perhaps someone else may be able to help.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Going to remove that information and keep this question directly for WinRM.

Comment: Okay, just double checking your case:  You are trying to remotely connect from two different servers (A and B) in the UI, to configure a server C.  In both servers A and B you are getting the same WinRM error in the UI?   The specific error text is from the UI connecting locally at its own machine (either or A or B) to a PowerShell workflow engine called M3P via a PowerShell local configuration named "microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows."  On the UI machines (A or B) you can call `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` from PowerShell and should see something by that name.

Comment: In both cases you should be able to call from Server A or B to C via `Install-WindowsFeature` which bypasses the workflow engine.  `Install-WindowsFeature` may still use components for the role/feature install installed on A or B to configure the remote server C (depends on the role or feature.)   Most of the heavy lifting is directly at the targeted server C via WMI and DISM.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I am only trying to Call A to B or B to A to install roles from the Server Manager GUI. On both servers it says the same runspace pool error mere seconds after starting install of any role or feature.

Comment: In either case, it sounds like they both are similarly fouled either in their configuration of the `microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows` endpoint or something deeper.  Can you add to your post the output of `Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows | fl *`?

Comment: Sure bare with me.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Added.

Comment: It needs the `| format-list *` portion of the command to have full output.  (`| fl *` for short.)  The basic part looks reasonable, but the real details are deeper in the output.  Compare that on a system that works, and you be able to spot a difference. `Set-PSSessionConfiguration` allows you to change the values if something wrong is found.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore I added it. Sorry about that. That portion didn't print on when I printed it to bring over to the machine.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious - though the ordering of your output is different than mine.  I'd suggest diffing before and after since you were able to check before group policy applied.  This layer relies on Windows Workflow - hard to know if you've set something related to that.  One last thing to try is to see if the endpoint basically works: `$s = new-pssession -configurationname microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows -ConnectionUri http://localhost:47001?MSP=7a83d074-bb86-4e52-aa3e-6cc73cc066c8
icm $s { get-command }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question when looking for the answer to another question. Please see [THIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/870874/what-is-a-winrm-runspace-pool) question for the fix to this issue.