# What is a WinRM runspace pool?

Tags: winrm

So I am having an issues installing/removing features and rolls from a Windows Server 2012 R2 Server. I consistently come up with this error no matter which service, role, or feature I installed called WinRM Runspace pool invalid. Now I know the two servers can talk to each other through Server Manager and I know they are using WinRM and WSMan but I don't understand how if they can talk to each other how their getting a Runspace pool error. So I guess to better understand the error after all of the fixes I have tried is to try and understand what a "Runspace Pool" is and how to troubleshoot it? I can't find any information from Microsoft on what it is. Can anyone explain and maybe how it affects my error I am getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Someone setup a different GPO that was above the one I was working on with the "Enable Windows Remote Shell" set to "Disabled". Set to "Not Configured" in my Patching GPO and can now Add/Remove Features.

```
Location: Computer Management\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Remote Shell
```

As stated in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1051813/how-to-properly-set-the-allow-remote-shell-access-setting-in-group-policy-so-a) question this setting can be very confusing. Since it says that setting it to "Not Configured" or "Disabled" it should be allowing the traffic and the use of the WinRM Pool but I guess for it to be fully accessible, then you have to have it set to "Not Configured"